# Angular 2: *ngIf - Template parse errors

Tags: angular

I am using Angular version 2.1.2 and I have error 'Template parse errors:(…)' when I'm running this code:

Component html:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
  <br />
  <div class="valign-wrapper">
    <div class="valign center" style="width:100%">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
        <i class="mdi mdi-vk"></i>
        Connect
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
})

export class HomeComponent {
  isLoggedIn = false;
}
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

import { routing } from './home.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
})

export class HomeModule {}
```

But if I use in html code for example '{{ isLoggedIn }} ' value is shown without any errors.

Please help me, what i forgot?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, thanks, as I thought that I forgot smthng :)

Answer (score 4):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    routing,
    CommonModule // <<<< added
  ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
})
```